# Oboe Async Audio Extraction

Tags: c++, audio, android-ndk, oboe

I am trying to build a **NDK** based C++ low latency audio player which will encounter three operations for multiple audios.

1. Play from assets.
2. Stream from an online source.
3. Play from local device storage.

From one of the **Oboe** samples provided by **Google**, I added another function to the class [NDKExtractor.cpp](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/samples/RhythmGame/src/main/cpp/audio/NDKExtractor.cpp) to extract a URL based audio and render it to audio device while reading from source at the same time.

```
int32_t NDKExtractor::decode(char *file, uint8_t *targetData, AudioProperties targetProperties) {

    LOGD("Using NDK decoder: %s",file);

    // Extract the audio frames
    AMediaExtractor *extractor = AMediaExtractor_new();
    // using this method instead of AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd() as used for asset files in the rythem game example
    media_status_t amresult = AMediaExtractor_setDataSource(extractor, file);


    if (amresult != AMEDIA_OK) {
        LOGE("Error setting extractor data source, err %d", amresult);
        return 0;
    }
    // Specify our desired output format by creating it from our source
    AMediaFormat *format = AMediaExtractor_getTrackFormat(extractor, 0);

    int32_t sampleRate;
    if (AMediaFormat_getInt32(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, &sampleRate)) {
        LOGD("Source sample rate %d", sampleRate);
        if (sampleRate != targetProperties.sampleRate) {
            LOGE("Input (%d) and output (%d) sample rates do not match. "
                 "NDK decoder does not support resampling.",
                 sampleRate,
                 targetProperties.sampleRate);
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        LOGE("Failed to get sample rate");
        return 0;
    };

    int32_t channelCount;
    if (AMediaFormat_getInt32(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, &channelCount)) {
        LOGD("Got channel count %d", channelCount);
        if (channelCount != targetProperties.channelCount) {
            LOGE("NDK decoder does not support different "
                 "input (%d) and output (%d) channel counts",
                 channelCount,
                 targetProperties.channelCount);
        }
    } else {
        LOGE("Failed to get channel count");
        return 0;
    }

    const char *formatStr = AMediaFormat_toString(format);
    LOGD("Output format %s", formatStr);

    const char *mimeType;
    if (AMediaFormat_getString(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME, &mimeType)) {
        LOGD("Got mime type %s", mimeType);
    } else {
        LOGE("Failed to get mime type");
        return 0;
    }

    // Obtain the correct decoder
    AMediaCodec *codec = nullptr;
    AMediaExtractor_selectTrack(extractor, 0);
    codec = AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType(mimeType);
    AMediaCodec_configure(codec, format, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
    AMediaCodec_start(codec);

    // DECODE

    bool isExtracting = true;
    bool isDecoding = true;
    int32_t bytesWritten = 0;

    while (isExtracting || isDecoding) {

        if (isExtracting) {

            // Obtain the index of the next available input buffer
            ssize_t inputIndex = AMediaCodec_dequeueInputBuffer(codec, 2000);
            //LOGV("Got input buffer %d", inputIndex);

            // The input index acts as a status if its negative
            if (inputIndex < 0) {
                if (inputIndex == AMEDIACODEC_INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                    // LOGV("Codec.dequeueInputBuffer try again later");
                } else {
                    LOGE("Codec.dequeueInputBuffer unknown error status");
                }
            } else {

                // Obtain the actual buffer and read the encoded data into it
                size_t inputSize;
                uint8_t *inputBuffer = AMediaCodec_getInputBuffer(codec, inputIndex,
                                                                  &inputSize);
                //LOGV("Sample size is: %d", inputSize);

                ssize_t sampleSize = AMediaExtractor_readSampleData(extractor, inputBuffer,
                                                                    inputSize);
                auto presentationTimeUs = AMediaExtractor_getSampleTime(extractor);

                if (sampleSize > 0) {

                    // Enqueue the encoded data
                    AMediaCodec_queueInputBuffer(codec, inputIndex, 0, sampleSize,
                                                 presentationTimeUs,
                                                 0);
                    AMediaExtractor_advance(extractor);

                } else {
                    LOGD("End of extractor data stream");
                    isExtracting = false;

                    // We need to tell the codec that we've reached the end of the stream
                    AMediaCodec_queueInputBuffer(codec, inputIndex, 0, 0,
                                                 presentationTimeUs,
                                                 AMEDIACODEC_BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                }
            }
        }

        if (isDecoding) {
            // Dequeue the decoded data
            AMediaCodecBufferInfo info;
            ssize_t outputIndex = AMediaCodec_dequeueOutputBuffer(codec, &info, 0);

            if (outputIndex >= 0) {

                // Check whether this is set earlier
                if (info.flags & AMEDIACODEC_BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) {
                    LOGD("Reached end of decoding stream");
                    isDecoding = false;
                } else {
                    // Valid index, acquire buffer
                    size_t outputSize;
                    uint8_t *outputBuffer = AMediaCodec_getOutputBuffer(codec, outputIndex,
                                                                        &outputSize);

                    /*LOGV("Got output buffer index %d, buffer size: %d, info size: %d writing to pcm index %d",
                         outputIndex,
                         outputSize,
                         info.size,
                         m_writeIndex);*/

                    // copy the data out of the buffer
                    memcpy(targetData + bytesWritten, outputBuffer, info.size);
                    bytesWritten += info.size;
                    AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer(codec, outputIndex, false);
                }

            } else {

                // The outputIndex doubles as a status return if its value is < 0
                switch (outputIndex) {
                    case AMEDIACODEC_INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                        LOGD("dequeueOutputBuffer: try again later");
                        break;
                    case AMEDIACODEC_INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                        LOGD("dequeueOutputBuffer: output buffers changed");
                        break;
                    case AMEDIACODEC_INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                        LOGD("dequeueOutputBuffer: output outputFormat changed");
                        format = AMediaCodec_getOutputFormat(codec);
                        LOGD("outputFormat changed to: %s", AMediaFormat_toString(format));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Clean up
    AMediaFormat_delete(format);
    AMediaCodec_delete(codec);
    AMediaExtractor_delete(extractor);
    return bytesWritten;
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is that this code first extracts all the audio data, saves it into a buffer which then becomes part of `AFileDataSource` which I derived from `DataSource` class in the same sample.
And after it's done extracting the whole file it plays by calling the `onAudioReady()` for Oboe `AudioStreamBuilder`.
What I need is to play as it streams the chunk of audio buffer.

**Optional Query:** Also aside from the question it blocks the UI even though I created a foreground service to communicate with the NDK functions to execute this code. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably solved this already, but for future readers...
You need a FIFO buffer to store the decoded audio. You can use the Oboe's FIFO buffer e.g. oboe::FifoBuffer.
You can have a low/high watermark for the buffer and a state machine, so you start decoding when the buffer is almost empty and you stop decoding when it's full (you'll figure out the other states that you need).
As a side note, I implemented such player only to find at some later time, that the AAC codec is broken on some devices (Xiaomi and Amazon come to mind), so I had to throw away the AMediaCodec/AMediaExtractor parts and use an AAC library instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a ringBuffer (or use the one implemented in the oboe example `LockFreeQueue.h`) and copy the data on buffers that you send on the ringbuffer from the extracting thread. On the other end of the RingBuffer, the audio thread will get that data from the queue and copy it to the audio buffer. This will happen on `onAudioReady(oboe::AudioStream *oboeStream, void *audioData, int32_t numFrames)` callback that you have to implement in your class (look oboe docs). Be sure to follow all the good practices on the Audio thread (don't allocate/deallocate memory there, no mutexes and no file I/O etc.)

Optional query: A service doesn't run in a separate thread, so obviously if you call it from UI thread it blocks the UI. Look at other types of services, there you can have IntentService or a service with a Messenger that will launch a separate thread on Java, or you can create threads in C++ side using `std::thread`

Comment: Thanks, I will check the ringBuffer and yes eventually found out about the service issue already.